# Bearing(azimuth) and distance via 2 gps coordnates (c#)

Tags: math, gps, geolocation, geometry, geography

I'm trying to find the angle to north(bearing/azimuth) & distance between 2 gps coordinates. But obviously I have a mistake somewhere - it gives me wrong bearing&distance values. Please correct me where I'm wrong. Trying it in Unity 5 (c#).
Here is the code:

```
 public float pointX; 
 public float pointY; 
 public float lat1=55.500817f; 
 public float lat2=55.380680f; 
 public float lon1=37.568342f; 
 public float lon2=37.822586f; 
 public float azimuth;

 void Update () { 
 float dlon = lon2 - lon1; 
 float dlat = lat2 - lat1;

 pointX = Mathf.Sin(dlon* 0.01745329f)*Mathf.Cos(lat2* 0.01745329f); 
 pointY = Mathf.Cos (lat1* 0.01745329f) * Mathf.Sin (lat2* 0.01745329f) - Mathf.Sin (lat1* 0.01745329f) * Mathf.Cos (lat2* 0.01745329f) * Mathf.Cos (dlon*0.01745329f); 
    azimuth=Mathf.Atan2(pointX, pointY)*57.29578f;

 double distance = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlat/2*0.01745329),2.0)+(Math.Cos(lat1* 0.01745329)*Math.Cos(lat2* 0.01745329)* Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlon/2* 0.01745329),2.0)); 
 distance = 2.0*6376500.0*Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(distance),Math.Sqrt(1.0-distance));
```

where * 0.01745329f is the conversion from degrees to radians and *57.29578f is the conversion from radians to degrees

Comment: What's wrong with calculated values? Azimuth formula looks like right one here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html  May be, some +-Pi error?

Comment: Why don't you post your input values and the wrong output values ? What is the result you got, what is the result you expected?

Comment: for better readibilty replace your 0.0174.. with a constant called  toRad. same with toDeg

Comment: it gives me azimuth=41.6446 & distance=97.2321767148383 with the values

Comment: AlexWien sorry,
it gives me azimuth=41.6446 & distance=97.2321767148383 with the input values
 public float lat1=55.500817f; 
 public float lat2=55.380680f; 
 public float lon1=37.568342f; 
 public float lon2=37.822586f; 
The real distance is ~20800 and azimuth ~ 120 degrees.
I try different input values but no changes in output values

Comment: your code is unreadable, and that makes it difficult for you and us to find the bug. Please introduce a method (or function) with the lat1,lat2, lon1, lon2 as input paramters, and distanceMeters as return value. And use a toRadians constant instead of the ugly 0.0174

Comment: Ánother tipp to get the code look identical as the formula which makes it easser to find a bug; introduce rLat1 = lat1 * toRadians; , same for the other 3 lat/longs.

Comment: I checked your source at least the azimuth has no errors, and I use the same formula, it gives me heading = 129 . Are you sure you look at the correct output; print the input and outpout to console within the code. Next tip: try to change all float to double

Comment: i get pointx= 0.0025209875920285405, pointy = -0.0020921620920549278, azimuth = 129.68

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume all the angles are already converted to radians, and use Re as the Earth's mean radius, and we'll assume a spherical Earth model.  There are corrections for the ellipsoidal shape of the Earth but this will get you close.  I'll use python-style coding since I know nothing about C#.

```
#
#  North Distance of point 2 from point 1
#
dN = Re * dlat
#
#  East Distance of point 2 from point 1
#
dE = Re * dlon * cos(0.5 * (lat1 + lat2))
#
#  Distance between points
#
distance=math.sqrt(dN**2 + dE**2)
#
#  Azimuth to point 2 from point 1 in radians
#
azimuth=math.atan2(dE,dN)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is double asterisk? I dont know the meaning

Comment: this  means power 2, one can also write dN*dN which works in all progr. languages.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code (to java), 1:1
There is no bug in your azimuth code.

Either the cause is by usage of Mathf (float) instead of the double variant
 or you just look at the wrong data or wrong output.

As intermediate values I get:
pointx= 0.0025209875920285405,
pointy = -0.0020921620920549278,
azimuth = 129.68